# Is it possible to add background music (with or without video) to the login screen on a Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, applescript, bash

I've never seen this question asked before, and provided that **Terminal** exists I don't see why this wouldn't be possible.

Does anyone know whether this is, or how they would make this possible?

Comment: I’m curious as to why you would want to do this...

Comment: Well, why not? Wouldn’t it be cool to try it out? And, if this is possible, thing of the other things that could be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a nice idea !
I have just seen that you can play sound with the program afplay, you can look how to use it here : https://osxdaily.com/2009/10/27/play-mp3s-and-other-music-from-the-command-line/ .
One way to do it could be at startup at the first login screen, you can look how to do it here : https://superuser.com/questions/245713/whats-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-script-run-at-boot-time-in-os-x .

Comment: Thank you so much, i’m so glad to see that it is possible!!